# Problems related to the apply call

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one function and I call it once,But when I run it in browser,It seems to run two times.

```js
function max() {
 console.log( arguments[0] );
 return this.max.apply( Math, Array.from( arguments[0] ) );
}

console.log( max( [1,32,42,1] ) );

/*
This is output of console:
------------------------
[1, 32, 42, 1]
1
-Infinity
*/
```

I want get the maximum value of an array,and I already know how to get it now.I just wonder why this function seems like execute twice and why this function can not get the right result.

Comment: `this`refers to `window` and `global-functions` are `properties` of `window-object`. `Function#apply` invokes the function with passed `this` argument as `this` context in `called-function`

Comment: Is there some particular reason you are using `arguments[0]` instead of just a regular parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `this` refers to window object so int just calling the same function recursively since `window.max` refers to the same function. On the second call, `this` refers to `Math` since you are defined `Math` as this argument in [`Fuction#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). While calling max function recursively the first argument would be `1` and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) creates an empty array so [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) return `-Infinity` as a result.

To make it work replace `this` with `Math` object although [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is not necessary at all.

```
function max() {
    return Math.max.apply( Math,arguments[0]);
}
```

---

Or simply pass the array as a normal argument.

```
function max(arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}
```

Comment: Because of `Function#apply`

Comment: Does the 2nd call equal to `Math.max([])`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.max.apply`

```
function max() {
    //console.log( arguments[0] );
    return Math.max.apply( Math, arguments[0]);
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `Array.from(arguments[0])`, instead of just writing `vals`, where `vals` is the parameter to the function?

Comment: @torazaburo yes you are right we can use  arguments[0] as it is instead of  `Array.from(arguments[0])` , thanks ;) good catch

Answer (score 1):

```
function max() {
console.log( arguments[0] );
return this.max.apply( Math, Array.from( arguments[0] ) );
}
```

In this method `this`refers to window as @JaydipJ mentions. If you want to pass Math object;

```
function max(){
var x=this.max.apply(null,[0,1,2,3]);
console.log(x);
}

max.apply(Math);
```